# Meaning of: "$M'$ is the kernel of the canonical surjective morphism" and "$\text{Im} f$ is the kernel of $\text{Coker }f$?"

Tags: notation, definition, morphism

The following is taken from: $\textit{Groups, Rings, Modules}$ by:  Auslander and Buchsbaum

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Proposition:}$  Let $M$ be an $R-$module.

Supppose $f:M\to N$ is a morphism of $R-$modules.  Then:

$(a)$ if $M'$ is a submodule of $M,$ then $M'$ is the kernel of the canonical surjective morphism $k_{M/M'}:M\to M/M'.$

$(b)$ $f$ is the zero morphism if and only if $\text{Ker} f=M.$
$\text{Im} f$ is the kernel of $\text{Coker }f,$ that is, $\text{Im }f$ is the kernel of the surjective morphism $N\to \text{Coker }f.$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

For the proposition quoted above, what does it to say in more math notation, in part $(a)$ that $M'$ is the kernel of the canonical surjective morphism $k_{M/M'}:M\to M/M'?$  Does it mean that
$\text{ker }k_{M/M'}=\{m\in M':k_{M/M'}(m)=0\}$

and also for part $(b)$ where it says:  $\text{Im} f$ is the kernel of $\text{Coker }f.$  To translate their "that is..." part.  Let the morphism $N\to \text{Coker }f.$ be denoted by $b,$ then $b:N\to \text{Coker }f,$ and $\text{Im }f=\text{ker }b=\{n\in N:b(n)=0\}.$

Thank you in advance