# Clarifications need for passages explaining about cokernel, kernel, image and co-image in Cohn's $\textit{Further Algebra with Applications}$ text

Tags: notation, definition, morphism

The following is taken from pg 37-38 of: *Further Algebra with Applications* by: P Cohn. It is also a continuation of [Meaning of: "$M'$ is the kernel of the canonical surjective morphism" and "$\text{Im} f$ is the kernel of $\text{Coker }f$?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794285/meaning-of-m-is-the-kernel-of-the-canonical-surjective-morphism-and-tex)

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

Let $A$ be an additive category; given a map $\alpha:X\to Y,$ we shall define the kernel of $\alpha$ as a certain subobject of $X.$   Consider all maps $\lambda:
A\to X$ such that $\lambda\alpha=0;$ for fixed $\alpha$ awe obtain a category by taking these maps as $\lambda$ as objects and as morphisms from $\lambda$ to $\lambda'$ maps $\varphi$ from the source of $\lambda$ to that of $\lambda'$ such that $\lambda=\varphi\lambda',$ with the obvious composition rule (obtained by composing maps in $A$).  A final object in this category, if one exists, is called a *kernel* of $\alpha$.  Thus a kernel of $\alpha$ is a map $\lambda:A\to X$ such that $\lambda\alpha=0$ and any other map $\lambda':A'\to X$ satisfying $\lambda'\alpha=0$ can be factored uniquely by $\lambda$, i.e. we have $\lambda'=\varphi\lambda$ for a unique map $\varphi$./ This can be expressed more briefly by saying that the kernel is the largest subobject 'killed' (i.e. mapped to $0$) by $\alpha$. The kernel need not exist, but if it does, it is unique up to equivalence, and in fact is a subobject of $X$.

> For let $(A,\lambda)$ be the kernel and assume that $f\lambda=0;$ then by the uniqueness of the factorization, $f=0$. The kernel $A$ of $\alpha$ or also the map $\lambda$ to $X,$ will be denoted by $\text{ker }\alpha.\quad (1)$

Dually the *cokernel* of $\alpha:X\to Y$ is an initial object in the category of all maps $\mu:Y\to C$ such that $\alpha\mu=0$.  This is a quotient object of $Y$, unique up to equivalence if it exists; it (or also the map from $Y$) will be denoted by $\text{coker }\alpha$.
Given any map $\alpha:X\to Y,$ assume that $\text{ker }\alpha$, $\text{coker }\alpha$ exist.  Then we can define two further objects, the image of $\alpha$, a subobject of $Y,$ and the $\textit{coimage}$ of $\alpha$, a quotient object of $X$:

> $$\text{im }\alpha =\text{ker } \text{coker }\alpha, \text{coim }\alpha =\text{coker } \text{ker }\alpha\quad (2)$$

Again they need not exist, but if they do, they are unique up to equivalence.  Further we have the following diagram:

[image]

> Here $\text{coim }\alpha$ is the largest quotient of $X$ kiling $\text{ker }\alpha$, hence there is a map $\kappa:\text{coim }\alpha\to Y$ such that $\alpha=(\text{coim }\alpha)\kappa$. It follows that ($\text{coim }\alpha)\kappa(\text{coker }\alpha)=0;$ but $\text{coim }$ is epic, so $\kappa(\text{coker }\alpha)=0,\quad (3)$

and since $\text{im }\alpha$ is the largest subobject of $Y$ killed by $\text{coker }\alpha$, there is a unique map $\alpha:\text{coim }\alpha\to \text{im }\alpha$ to make the diagram commute.  If we had or proceeded in dual fashion, starting from $\text{im }\alpha$ and going via a map $X\to \text{im }\alpha$, we would have obtained another map $\alpha';:\text{coim }\alpha\to \text{im }\alpha$ to make the square commute,

> Now $\alpha=(\text{coim }\alpha)\alpha'(\text{im }\alpha)=(\text{coim }\alpha)\alpha''(\text{im }\alpha);\quad (4)$

since $\text{coim }\alpha$ is epic and $\text{im }\alpha$ is monic, it follows that $\alpha'=\alpha''$, so the maps coincide and there is complete symmetry.  In important cases $\alpha'$ is an isomorphism.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I have some questios about different places of the quoted passages above. I have indented the relevant passage and numbered them for ease of references.  In the $(1)$ above, where did the map $f$ come from?  Also when it says: the map $\lambda$ to $X,$ will be denoted by $\text{ker }\alpha$.   What does Cohn mean by the map $\lambda$ to $X$?  The map $\lambda$ should be a map from $A\to X$.

In $(2)$, the notations: $\text{ker } \text{coker }\alpha, \text{coker } \text{ker }\alpha$, what does it mean in terms of maps.  So if I have a map $\alpha$, do I take the cokernel of $alpha$, and then create another map out of that, then take the kernel of that resulting map.  SImilarly for $\text{coker } \text{ker }\alpha$.

For $(3)$ and $(4),$ the notations:  $(\text{coim }\alpha)\kappa$, $\text{coim }\alpha)\kappa(\text{coker }\alpha)$, $\kappa(\text{coker }\alpha)$, $(\text{coim }\alpha)\alpha'(\text{im }\alpha),(\text{coim }\alpha)\alpha''(\text{im }\alpha)$, are they composition of maps, sets, or both?  Say $(\text{coim }\alpha)\kappa$, is that a compositoin of a direct image of a map with another map?  or is it a multiplication of a set with a map?

Thank you in advance

Comment: There appears to be a high degree of overlap with this question and one I gave a detailed response to a few days ago as well as others you have asked recently.  I also note that when a contributor takes a lot of time to review your work and provide a detailed answer with multiple follow-ups that it is good form to formally accept and upvote the answer!

Comment: @AlgTop1854 this is also a follow up to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4795233/how-to-understand-the-meaning-of-kernel-cokernel-coimage-etc-of-another-morph)  I know there might be some overlap, but in this post and the other one, it is in the context of category theory, and I am learning about modules and exact sequences, and similar things are coming up, and in the case of category theory, I am seeing a map is simply call kernel, cokernel, etc.  Also, when it is talking about kernel and cokernel, I see  notations like...

Comment: @AlgTop1854 ...$(\text{coim }\alpha)\kappa$. or $\text{coker }(\text{ker }\alpha$ which I don't really understand what it means.

Comment: **Stop** using MathJax to write italic and bold **text**. And for the $n$th time, the punctuation goes **outside** math mode in in-line formulas. Eleven years, almost 300 questions, you shouldn't still be misusing formatting.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am confusing, which syntax is mathjax and which one is Latex?  I use \textit before and then I am told to use *____*, but when i use the later, I am told to use the former.  I just don't see the difference, they are isomorphically equivalent as far as display result goes. And what does it mean by punctuation goes outside math mode.  This is the $n=1-$st time i have seen you telling me about this issue. I don't see why it is call misusing formatting, when it does what I want to display.  I am not crashing the site by using equivalent latex syntax?

Comment: MathJax = Latex. It's everything you write between dollar signs. For italic and bold  text *outside of math formulas* (like when you have the word "cokernel") use **mark up**. Which I have described to you **multiple times**. MathJax/LaTex is more bandwidth expensive, spacing is different, and the typeface is different, and depends far more on local implementation. They are not "isomorphically equivalent". How do you think I can tell that you are doing it?  because they **look** different.

Comment: Punctuation: periods, commas, colons. `$n=1.$` renders the period as a decimal point, because it is *inside* an in line formula. The spacing is wrong. To get a period, which is what that is, you shoukd write `$n=1$.`, with the punctuation *outside* the in-line formula.

Comment: Anything here inside the dollar signs or double dollar signs is MathJax which is the version of Latex supported here, so you need not distinguish them.  Otherwise I'd suggest looking at the writing of more experienced users to get a feel for what is better form and looks better. IMO, including the formatting issues, the above question comes across as many questions and quite jumbled.  Perhaps find a way to clean it up and ask no more than two related ones at a time even though they all fit in, and you could even refer to your others and note why this one is different.  Redundant now.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin how do you mean this look different?  When I put asterisk in between text versus when I put the text inside curly braces of \textit{}, it comes out looking text that got italicized.  Same thing for making letters look bold, etc.

Comment: How it looks depends on your local implementation. As to the punctuation, this is [not the first time I've told you](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4793852/need-help-with-understanding-the-proof-for-let-fm-to-n-be-a-morphism-of-r).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin what does local implementation mean? By the way, I have rarely have to type latex beyond doing it on math.stackexchange.  It is only this year that I have boungt winedit to learn how to use it seriously on my own computer.

Comment: Local implementation is how you are accessing the site (which device, browser, system) and how that device renders text vs how it renders math. What you see is not necessarily identical to what I see.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 I try to make it all in one post since they are just requested clarification of exposition or about notations.  They are all about similar concepts, cokernel, kernel, image, coimage and how they are used or seems to be used/defined differently.

Comment: Then I'll say that even though it just comes down to definitions and such and nothing so deep, that this one may be tough to make work here.  I'm not going to tackle this one as stated above. Spelling, punctuation, formatting and style issues are only making it harder. I hope this was helpful but I'll leave any formal responses to others.

Comment: When you use `\textit` inside Mathjax, the system uses a single font of a particular size; same with `\textbf`. If it is text **within a formula**, then that's what you should use; for example, if you are describing a function defined by cases. But when it is in the middle of te text, depending on your local system, it could show up substantially larger, substantially smaller, in a completely different font (serf vs sans serif, etc). So when you want words in bold or italic *in the middle of text* (not in the middle of formulas), you use mark-up, not LaTeX/MathJax. (cont)

Comment: Similar problems arise with punctuation. For **displayed** formulas (double dollar signs) the punctuation (parentheses, commas, periods, colons) go *inside* the double dollar signs so that they show up in the same line as the displayed formula. But for in-line formulas (single dollar signs), they go outside because they are not part of the mathematical formula. A period at the end of a sentence that ends with $0$ is not the same as a decimal point following a $0$ (different spacing). When you wrote `$n=1-$st`, you got a *minus sign*; had you written `$n=1$-st`, you'd would have gotten a hyphen

Comment: Compare the dash in the first, " $n=1-$st", with the dash in the second: " $n=1$-st". Compare `$R$-module`: $R$-module; with `$R-$module`: $R-$module. And perhaps you will note the difference in sizes here in the comments between surrounding text and $\textit{LaTeX textit italic}$ (slightly larger because the font size is fixed).  Proper formatting makes it far more likely that *everyone* will see a post that is readable, regardless of their system or local implementation.